# How to prevent div contents from "panning" vertically when touched on mobile? - it interferes with vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I am currently building a slider using Swiffy Slider (swiffyslider.com), however, on mobile the contents of the slides are taller than the viewport. This results in the user getting "stuck" trying to scroll past the slider if they've interacted with it.

It looks like the child div is being dragged around the parent it clips within.

I'd like to prevent the users vertical touch interactions from disabling their ability to seamlessly scroll down the page.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue concerning sliders/carousels and if so, how did you fix it?

I've tried setting the elements to be non-draggable, but that seems to have no effect. I've also tried a number of CSS rules concerning touch interactions - also to no avail.

````
<div class="xl:!hidden swiffy-slider slider-item-reveal mx-auto max-w-[375px] my-8 slider-nav-outside slider-item-first-visible slider-nav-visible">

        <ul class="slider-container !overflow-y-clip bg-[#011620]">
            @* Individual Column Begins*@
            @foreach (var truck in Model.Trucks)
            {
                <li class="flex flex-col mx-12">
                    <img src="@truck.Image.Src" alt="@truck.Image.Alt" />
                    <h2 class="text-4xl mb-12 text-white mt-6">@truck.Title</h2>
                    <h3 class="mb-3 text-white text-xl !normal-case">@Html.Raw(truck.Header)</h3>
                    @*Attributes Go Here *@
                    <div draggable="false">
                        @foreach (var detail in truck.Details)
                        {
                            <div class="flex flex-row justify-between space-x-4 border-t border-[#162931] py-4 pr-12">
                                <p class="font-light text-white max-w-[16ch]">@Html.Raw(detail.Label)</p>
                                <div class="min-w-[100px]">
                                    <p class="font-semibold text-white max-w-[10ch]">@Html.Raw(detail.Value)</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    @if (truck.Link != null)
                    {
                        <a href="@truck.Link.Url" target="@truck.Link.Target"
                           class="mt-8 !text-white !font-semibold">@truck.Link.Name<span class="text-red"> ></span></a>
                    }
                </li>
            }
        </ul>

        <button type="button" class="slider-nav slider-nav-round"></button>
        <button type="button" class="slider-nav slider-nav-next slider-nav-round"></button>

    </div>```
````

Comment: Please add your code so as to make a [mre]. We can't and don't want to guess what your problem looks like.

Comment: Code has been added!